# get nanosecond timestamp in Unix epoch php

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

PHP `strtotime` gives unix timestamp, but how to get the nanosecond timestamp in unix epoch. I want to get it to store it in my influxdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not provide a function that has higher precision than microseconds, unfortunately. The UNIX timestamp, according to the standard, is stored in microseconds.
However, there is a **platform-dependent** solution. Use

> system('date %N');

on a linux machine. See **man date** or [this page](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udate.htm) for more info.